# Have a firefox extension recognise a tel: tag and hangle it?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, tel

I'm developing a click-to-dial tool, and would like to pass all tel: links in firefox to my extension, which will then run click to dial

so

```
<a href="tel:01223236103">Call this customer</a>
```

should silently be passed to my extension to deal with and not ask the user which external application they wish to launch

This is primarily for Mac users although it should ideally be a cross-platform solution (so handled within the JavaScript rather than using any external applications)

Any suggestions where to look/what to Google?

Comment: You're going to want to make a userscript or something similar to run through all the anchor tags. Try looking at parsing HTML via Firefox extension code.

Comment: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by writing and registering my own protocol handler

1. [Mike's blog gives a helpful walkthrough](http://mike.kaply.com/2011/01/18/writing-a-firefox-protocol-handler/)
2. [Mozillazine explains what you're doing](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol)

Answer (score 0):

How protocol URLs are handled is something that's determined by the operating system. You can see more details in [this article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol).

What you'll want to do is run a [content script](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.12/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/index.html) on each page to detect `tel:` links and register a click handler on them. This click handler could perform the action you want, then return `false` to prevent any further action being taken.